# Memozied Fibonacci not Running vs Regular Fibonacci Solution

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

So I am learning dynamic programming, and I am trying to test my memoized solution vs the normal fibonacci solution.
When I put in a fairly large number like 43, my memoized solution takes forever to run, while the normal solution, runs after 5 - 6 seconds. Does this mean my memoized solution isn't actually storing the already seen results?

Here is my traditional solution:

```
public static int fibonacci(int i) 
{
    if(i == 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(i <= 2) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2);
}
```

Memoized Solution:

```
public static int fibonacci(int n) 
{
    Map<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
    if(n == 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(memo.containsKey(n))
    {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    int result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    memo.put(n, result); 
    
    return result;
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println(fibonacci(n));
}
```

Any explanation as to why this is the case would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Indeed it's not memoized. You're creating a new map for each call.

Comment: Ah that would make sense, does this mean I would have to make the map an instance variable outside of the method?

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @shmosel I was able to figure out that during my 'memoized' solution, I was calling a new map everytime the method was called causing it to be extremely slow! I circumvented this by adding the map as an instance variable as follows:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();

public static int fibonacci(int n) 
{
    if(n == 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(memo.containsKey(n))
    {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    int result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    memo.put(n, result); 

    return result;
}
```

This has dramatically increased performance.